# Can Speech Recognition make difference between two human voices?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm making a Speech to Text app and i want it distinguish each human voice. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO !! speech recognition or **ASR** cant help you differentiate between two people voices. you need to study about **DSP**(Digital Signal Processing) technology to do that.

**DSP** processing is so heavy for a mobile device and normally its done using servers the proper way to achieve this is sending the recorded voice to the server and processing it.

voice recognition will just help you to recognize the words while speaker recognition will help you to realize the speaker. google "speaker recognition". there is also a tool called ALIZE that does this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about distinguishing kind of sound. For example clap sound from drums sound.

Comment: the same. using 'Digital Signal Processing' technology you can do it, while ALIZE cant i think.

Comment: Got it ! Many thanks!